# Unable to 'Grant admin consent to the add-in' when enabling SSO for OfficeJS app

Tags: office-js, office365api, office365-apps

I'm attempting the build a Microsoft first party app using OfficeJS.  In trying to enable the app to retrieve an SSO token, I can't "grant admin consent to the add-in".  When I try to navigate to

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id={application_ID}&state=12345`

with my app_id plugged in, I get a permissions denied message.  {App name} needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it.

I am attempting this through a Microsoft work account.  Is this feature strictly limited to O365 accounts?

Answer (score 0):

The feature is currently in preview and only works with Office 365 (work or school) accounts at this time. (Not Microsoft Accounts.) To grant admin consent you must be logged in as an admin of the O365 tenancy.